# best practices for managing space

Tags: administration, community

We are still relatively new in the Salesforce world.  We thought we sized our site to get us through a year of processing, but have run out of space in 8 months.  We are concerned that we may not be managing space utilization wisely.  Would anyone be willing to share hints and tips on ways to better manage this beast?

Thank you.

Comment: Can I ask what type of storage (file or data?) and what edition of Salesforce you use?

Comment: We've reached our capacity on data space.  Looking at their measurements, our biggest culprit is iContact.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to contact iContact and see if they can help pinpoint anything for you.

Comment: iContact support was not much help.  I think I narrowed down the iContact objects to be iContactforSF__iContact_Clicked_Link__c (few records), iContactforSF__iContact_Message_Statistic__c (lots of records), iContactforSF__iContact_Sent_Message__c (few records).  My question is:  those who use iContact, do you manage these objects separate from the Campaign objects?